# How to access results of hibernate group by results

Tags: hibernate

how can i access Hibernate group by results. I try to get counts of the operation grouped by its date. My code is here:

```
Criteria crit = sess().createCriteria(Attendance.class);
        crit.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("date"),"adate")
                .add(Projections.rowCount(),"trueCount" ));
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("status", true));
        List l = crit.list();
```

Right results is loaded to List. How can i access the results inside this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should return a list of `Object[]` which `Object[0]` is for the `adate` alias (Date) and `Object[1]` is for the `trueCount` (Integer) , so you can access the results in the returned list by:

```
List<Object[]> l = (List<Object[]>)crit.list();

for(Object[] result: l ){
   Date adate = (Date)result[0];
   Integer trueCount = (Integer)result[1]; 
}
```